# JPA 2 multiple @CollectionTable in Entity causing unrelated outer joins

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Hi I have the following JPA entity class. It has two @CollectionTable mapping for Groups and Contact Id's. I am interesting in getting back a list of unique contact id's from the contact_details table and having a reference to them in my **Users** class variable **contacts** below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private UUID id;

@NotBlank
private String username;

@NotBlank
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "users_groups", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "[group]")
private List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "contact_detail", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "[id]")
private List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

When I get a user from the database it produces the following query in the hibernate logs

```
select user0_.id, user0_.password, user0_.username, contacts1_.user_id as user_id8_4_1_, contacts1_."id" as id1_2_1_, groups2_.user_id as user_id1_4_2_, groups2_."group" as group2_5_2_ 
from users user0_ 
left outer join contact_detail contacts1_ on user0_.id=contacts1_.user_id 
left outer join users_groups groups2_ on user0_.id=groups2_.user_id 
where user0_.id=?
```

Because of the Left Outer Join on **contact_detail** and **users_groups**, it actually retrieves back the same contact_id multiple times. This is a JSON representation of the entity with multiple "47e5b98a-2116-4ad9-b773-3acc99e2c83c" contact id's

```
{
user: {
    id: "d3b3be2a-8a2a-48ac-94dd-fd85faf1a8ff",
    username: "shiv",
    firstName: "Shivam",
    lastName: "Sinha",
    groups: [
        "ADMIN",
        "USER",
        "ROOT"
    ],
    expired: false,
    locked: false,
    credentialsExpired: false,
    enable: true,
    birthday: "2015-05-18",
    joined: "2015-05-18",
    gender: "M",
    contactDetails: null,
    contacts: [
        "47e5b98a-2116-4ad9-b773-3acc99e2c83c",
        "47e5b98a-2116-4ad9-b773-3acc99e2c83c",
        "47e5b98a-2116-4ad9-b773-3acc99e2c83c"
    ]
}
}
```

However when I completely remove the following groups class variable:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "users_groups", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "[group]")
private List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
```

And attempt to retrieve the the user from the database. Hibernate generates the following sql:

```
select user0_.id, user0_.password, user0_.username, contacts1_.user_id as     user_id8_4_1_, contacts1_."id" as id1_2_1_ 
from users user0_ left outer join contact_detail contacts1_ on user0_.id=contacts1_.user_id 
where user0_.id=?
```

This is the JSON representation of the entity:

```
{
user: {
    id: "d3b3be2a-8a2a-48ac-94dd-fd85faf1a8ff",
    username: "shiv",
    firstName: "Shivam",
    lastName: "Sinha",
    expired: false,
    locked: false,
    credentialsExpired: false,
    enable: true,
    birthday: "2015-05-18",
    joined: "2015-05-18",
    gender: "M",
    contacts: [
        "47e5b98a-2116-4ad9-b773-3acc99e2c83c"
    ]
}
}
```

It only contains unique contact id "47e5b98a-2116-4ad9-b773-3acc99e2c83c". Which is what is expected.

So my question is how can i achieve the same thing without having to remove **groups** class variable OR changing the datatype from `List<String> contacts` to `Set<String> contacts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour that is happening now is as expected as can be seen from the hibernate [FAQ](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword.).The solution is mentioned in the FAQ here as well

If you are looking to do this via JPA refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031690/criteria-api-fetch-of-a-list-returns-repeated-main-entity).

Following is the implementation in Spring data using the following Specification

```
 public class UserSpecifications {

    public static Specification<User> findUniqueUser(Integer userId){

         return new Specification<User>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> userRoot,
                    CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQ, CriteriaBuilder critieriaB) {
                criteriaQ.distinct(true);
                return critieriaB.equal(userRoot.get(User_.id), 1);
            }

         };
    }
}
```

To find the record

```
User user = userRepository.findOne(UserSpecifications.findUniqueUser(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at this

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies .

> If you use fetch="join" for more than one collection role for a
>   particular entity instance (in "parallel"), you create a Cartesian
>   product (also called cross join) and two (lazy or non-lazy) SELECT
>   would probably be faster.

This Cartesian product is what you are describing (multiple values). Try attempting to change it to use select as suggested:

@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) or Alternatively also try the batch Mode.

This is a further explanation of the fetching strategies: 
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/